# python subprocess call variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, ansible

I want to execute below ansible playbook using python, can some one help me with subprocess for a variable?

Have a variable called var1

```
var1=APP1
subprocess.check_call(["/bin/ansible-playbook", "PlayBook.yml", "--extra-vars", "appName=var1"])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that, you want `var1` to be put in the `check_call`?

```py
subprocess.check_call(["/bin/ansible-playbook", "PlayBook.yml", "--extra-vars", f"appName={var1}"])
```

Comment: Yeah that's right, tried the one suggested above but it turn out to be a invalid syntax. Basically am trying to achieve executing the ansible command with python like below with a variable.   Command: ""/bin/ansible-playbook PlayBook.yml --extra-vars appName={var1}"". Python version: 2.7

Answer (score 0):

I think its because of version, f string was introduced on 3.x. I was using 2.7 was able to achieve this through format method.

Thanks